# audiotrack position update windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, audiotrack, background-audio

I am playing audio through the background audio player agent. How do I display a progress bar in the foreground indicating what position is the track currently add, like the built-in music player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [Rob Crocombe blog](http://robcrocombe.com/2012/06/15/how-to-make-an-audio-progress-bar/) you can find how to make a progressbar and use it with Background audio player. It works basing on Dispatcher Timer, which you start along with play button - the music is playing in background, timer is working in main UI and it's updating progres bar.
On the other hand, if you want  want to make a slider (to be able to jump to selected position) you can use (as it's showed in blog) SuperSlider from Toolkit or you can customize your own slider as it showed [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/customizing-wp7-slider-in-different-ways).

Answer (score 0):

I done this same using Media element there i used a progressbar and Dispatcher timer on dispatcher timer tik event i updated the status of progress bar

Comment: But I have to use a background audio player.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone Background Audio with Slider and Timer

[you can find here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-Background-ece718b4)

Comment: While this link may provide an answer to the question, links can break over time. Please include a description of your answer.